# Is it possible to remove items from "System Settings"

Tags: system-settings

I would like to remove or disable some unused settings panels in system settings/gnome-control-center to keep my more "ambitious" users from messing with them.
Specifically, I would like to disable/remove the following:

- Printers (because we don't have any attached to these machines)
- Details (because it lets you set actions on removable media)
- Keyboard (because it lets you set shortcut keys - not a dealbreaker)

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward (I can remove them from the Applications menu by setting `Hidden=true` in the `.desktop` file associated with the panel), but they stubbornly remain in System Settings when I do that.

Am I missing something, or are we stuck with these panels in the Settings application forever?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Given that changing the permissions accomplishes your goal, check out this magic:

```
dpkg-statoverride --update --add root root 640 /usr/share/applications/gnome-printers-panel.desktop
dpkg-statoverride --update --add root root 640 /usr/share/applications/gnome-info-panel.desktop
dpkg-statoverride --update --add root root 640 /usr/share/applications/gnome-keyboard-panel.desktop
```

You can remove the overrides with:

```
dpkg-statoverride --remove /path/to/file
```

(but note this won't reset the original permissions)

Comment: This is probably the most elegant general-purpose solution (and seems the most likely to survive across package and release upgrades)

Answer (score 7):

OK, I *think* I found a workaround -- `gnome-control-center` doesn't respect `Hidden=true` in the `gnome-whatever-panel.desktop` file, but it's not smart enough to display a panel if you ***completely remove*** the associated `.desktop` file.

So for the panels I've listed you can remove/disable them by deleting the following files:

```
/usr/share/applications/gnome-printers-panel.desktop
/usr/share/applications/gnome-info-panel.desktop
/usr/share/applications/gnome-keyboard-panel.desktop
```

> As [MikeyB noted in his comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442520/is-it-possible-to-remove-items-from-system-settings/442556?noredirect=1#comment578981_442556) making these files unreadable by "other" is also an option - I tested this (`chmod 640`) on a spare box and it appears to work, disabling the panels for "normal" users while still leaving them available to `root` and members of the `root` group.

---

There are two notable disadvantages to this approach:

1. This completely disables those panels for *ALL* users.
   You can't even invoke them manually by running `gnome-control-center info` or similar [as Radu Rădeanu mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/442540/121565) - They just won't launch.
2. Updates to `gnome-control-center` & related packages *may* bring the panels back.
   This basically means checking after each software update to be sure they're still gone (or have appropriately restrictive permissions), and deleting/`chmod`ing the `.desktop` files again if necessary.

For my purposes neither of those are a huge issue since I configure these machines from the command line anyway & the system settings panels are just for users to make minor "personality tweaks" so unless this workaround

Comment: Rather than removing, does it still do what you want if you restrict read permissions to certain groups (i.e. everybody except root and you)?

Comment: @MikeyB Possibly - the machine I would test such things on is currently building a release with the files deleted though so I can't test that just now - that would be a good way to mitigate #1. (It would still likely be stomped on by updates though, so you're left being vigilant for them coming back anyway.)

Comment: If you look inside of `/usr/share/applications/gnome-info-panel.desktop` file you will see that it is using `gnome-control-center info`. So, this command will work without problems if you delete that desktop file.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu No, it won't - At least not on the machine I tested it on. (If you run `gnome-control-center info` after deleting the info-panel desktop file the control center opens, but it drops you on the "All Settings" page -- the panel doesn't load.)

Answer (score 3):

No, unfortunately you can't remove any of **Printers**, **Details**, or **Keyboard** from **System Settings**. These are called "PANELS" and are hard coded in the `gnome-control-center` package. If you remove this package, you will not have **System Settings** anymore.

Let say that you remove those icons and names from the main panel of **System Settings**. Anyway, a user can open any one of them from terminal using one of the following commands:

```
gnome-control-center info
gnome-control-center keyboard
gnome-control-center printers
```

See `man gnome-control-center` for more info.

Comment: We've already essentially denied our users access to the terminal (or at least made it *really inconvenient*) so having them invoke something by typing a command is generally not an issue, but this is more or less the answer I was expecting. (It then begs the question of why I can remove *other* panels easily enough by deleting an underlying package, but these *particular ones* are welded into the base package making them all-or-nothing, but that's a separate rant…)