# Is there an application like the GNOME system settings which is more modular (remove some devices, leave others)?

Tags: unity, system-settings

I'm looking for a GUI application which works as nicely as Ubuntu's system settings, except that it lets me remove some of the items in it without the whole thing crashing.

In the current GUI, removing one of the modules (for devices like bluetooth, printers) has -in the past- made the whole system settings (GUI) application disappear.

I want to make it more difficult for anyone to use such devices (printer, bluetooth) through my computer (until -if ever- I decide otherwise).

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what you mean; how: remove one of the devices? From the launcher?

Comment: I edited it.  I hope it's clearer. Is it? (@Jacob Vlijm) Thanks.

Comment: I think I got it, you want to remove items from the *settings* manager (System settings >), not from Unity. The crashing is obviously not the "normal behaviour. maybe worth to try to fix it?

Comment: Hm. Not sure.  I thought there'd be another program wich didn't crash.  Didn't know it was NOT the usual behavior, but saw others asking similar questions, so I figured I wasn't the only one having problems with that part of System Settings.  A plain "no" might do for an answer :)  Thanks, though.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://askubuntu.com/questions/442520/is-it-possible-to-remove-items-from-system-settings

Comment: I am afraid I am lost, obviously I don't understand the question, maybe someone else will?

Comment: I removed them from the "Ubuntu Software Center" individually, but the System Settings disappeared.  Let me hope someone will understand my question.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Ah, I see (chat). In the link above, you can read how to remove them from System settings.

Comment: Might just be getting too late for me.  Not quite willing to read it in detail.  Might have overlooked it.  Thanks again (@Jacob Vlijm).  Have a good one.

Comment: OK, last thing that might restore your System settings: http://askubuntu.com/questions/466720/system-settings-icons-missing-in-14-04 (not sure if that is what you are looking for as well)

Comment: I seems to me that you want to hide or remove some modules (not devices) from GUI (Control Center, not its backend, gnome settings deamon). Right?

Comment: Yes.  (@Sneetsher) I guess that's what that's called...just to make it more difficult for anyone to use such devices (printer, bluetooth) through my computer.

Answer (score 0):

- `unity-control-center` relys on `.desktop` files and their commands existence to show UI modules.

  1. That's what I got from tracing it.

     ```
     strace -o Desktop/trace_control_center.txt unity-control-center
     ```
  2. Click on printer then close it
  3. Check for operations: `stat`,if successful followed by `open`, itself if successful followed by `read`

     ```
     grep -i printer Desktop/trace_control_center.txt
     ```
- So, Just remove their `.desktop` file or change its permission:

  ```
  sudo chmod -r /usr/share/applications/unity-bluetooth-panel.desktop
  sudo chmod -r /usr/share/applications/system-config-printer.desktop
  ```

  BTW, `unity-control-center` is forked from `gnome-control-center`, same as `unity-settings-daemon` from `gnome-settings-daemon`. You may have both on same system:

  ```
  sudo chmod -r /usr/share/applications/gnome-bluetooth-panel.desktop
  ```

  Printer configuration wizard is common.
- Or you may instead change commands permission, if you want to disable both GUI/CLI:

  ```
  sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/system-config-printer
  ```