# Disable Printer Discovery Ubuntu 19

Tags: printing

This question seems to have been asked before without a definitive answer. I went to print a document today and had a dozen printers listed on my laptop. I travel with this and do not want to have to clean up the printers every time I touch a new network.

There must be some way to stop Ubuntu 19 from automatically adding printers. Is there an option for "manual only" printer setup? A way to turn of Bonjour or whichever print protocol is helping this feature?

Thanks

Comment: this is aknowing bug in gnome-control-center https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1765390  maybe you can kick the printer module this way https://askubuntu.com/questions/442520/is-it-possible-to-remove-items-from-system-settings/442599

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this is a bug and being worked on. Disabling the printer module will not work for me. Hopefully this will be a simple fix and addressed in an update.